# Powershell API Data Extraction

Tags: powershell

I'm getting data back from an API for a system of ours using Powershell but it doesn't quite return it correctly. It is putting the data all under one header as seen below. I'm trying to extract the downloadLink part only

Tried converting to JSON to see if I could get anywhere else with it.

```
$token = ".."
$web = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{'Authorization' = $token} 
echo $web
```

I get this as the outcome:

```
documents                                                                                                                                                                                     
---------                                                                                                                                                                                     
{@{documentName=Name.docx.pdf; downloadLink=https://app.xxx.com/api/docs/employees/111/shared/111}, {@{documentName=Name.docx.pdf; downloadLink=https://app.xxx.com/api/docs/employees/111/shared/111} ...
```

What I need to get is the `downloadLink`, but as it's all coming under the documents header I can't do a simple select or get on it.

Comment: Have you tried something like `$web.documents | Foreach-Object { $_.downloadLink }` ?

Comment: That worked, hadn't considered that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the results **from** JSON using [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)? See the code example below.

Please note the change I made to the ContentType to the Invoke-RestMethod as well.

```
$token = ".."
$web = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{'Authorization' = $token} 
$webResults = $web | ConvertFrom-Json
echo ($json | ConvertFrom-Json).downloadLink
```